# reorder an array elements based on first phrase in pattern of elements

Tags: javascript

I have a pairs array consist of an specific pattern (first phrase = second phrase). I want to reorder the pairs array based on first phrase (I give the first phrase as phrase variable)

This is not an easy task for me because I can't find a proper solution to reorder the pairs array elements when it's consists of two separate phrases...

```js
const pairs = ["they're = they are", "Your Majesty = your highness"];

const phrase = "your majesty"; // this is always lowercase

function reorderPairs() {
 // I want to bring "Your Majesty = your highness" to the first position
 
 // expected result would be: ["Your Majesty = your highness", "they're = they are"];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter pairs that matchs the phrase and then concat with the rest

```js
const pairs = ["they're = they are", "Your Majesty = your highness"]
const phrase = "your majesty"

function reorderPairs() {
  const pairsMatchPhrase = pairs.filter(
    (pair) => pair.split(" = ")[0].toLowerCase() === phrase
  )
  const pairsNotMatchPhrase = pairs.filter(
    (pair) => pair.split(" = ")[0].toLowerCase() !== phrase
  )
  return pairsMatchPhrase.concat(pairsNotMatchPhrase)
}

console.log(reorderPairs())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce() to examine each string, and unshift() the strings that include the phrase.

```js
const pairs = ["they're = they are", "Your Majesty = your highness"];
const phrase = "your majesty"; // this is always lowercase

function reorderPairs() {
  return pairs.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if(cur.toLowerCase().includes(phrase)){
      acc.unshift(cur)
    }else{
      acc.push(cur)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

console.log(reorderPairs())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Basically find the index of the string that's matching with the phrase, remove from the array and add it to the front. Below is the example

```js
const pairs = ["they're = they are", 'Your Majesty = your highness'];

const phrase = 'your majesty'; // this is always lowercase

function reorderPairs(data, phrase) {
  const index = data.findIndex(d => d.toLowerCase().includes(phrase));
  if (index !== -1) {
    const dataCopy = [...data];
    return [...dataCopy.splice(index, 1), ...dataCopy];
  }
  return [...data];
}

console.log(reorderPairs(pairs, phrase));
```